# Type on textfield when it has focus using button Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one button  that displays number "1" when clicked and three text boxes. I want when the  button is clicked the number is displayed on the text box that has focus. Can someone help me please.

```js
function run(){
  
document.calc.txt1.value += "1";
}
```

```html
<input type=button name="btn1" value="1" OnClick="run()"id="button"><br />
<form name="calc">
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2">
<input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt3">
</form>
```

t3">

Comment: No `<input>` element will have focus when the`<button>` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button, the previous `input` looses focus. You could try to store the last focused input element before the click:

(this needs some more work)

```js
var lastFocus = null;

document.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
  // Here, you'll need to find out if the blurred element
  // was one of your valid inputs. It's probably best to
  // identify them by a class name
  if (event.target.type === "text") {
    lastFocus = event.target;
  }
}, true);

function run() {
  // When the user hasn't yet focused on a text input,
  // the first one is used by default
  (lastFocus || document.calc.txt1).value += "1";
}
```

```html
<input type=button name="btn1" value="1" OnClick="run()"id="button"><br />
<form name="calc">
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2">
<input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt3">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currId;
function setId(curr){
  currId=curr.id;
  }
function run(){
  if(currId)
    {
      document.getElementById(currId).value +='1';
      }
//document.calc.txt1.value += "1";
  //document.activeElement.value += "1";
}
```

```html
<input type=button name="btn1" value="1" OnClick="run()"id="button"><br />
<form name="calc">
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" onblur="setId(this)">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2"  onblur="setId(this)">
<input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt3"  onblur="setId(this)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this code snippet should do what you want. The main thing to note though is that whenever you click the button, the input box becomes blurred that you had selected.

Essentially what this code does here is set the onfocus attribute to allow you to figure out which input box was last focused, rather than which input box IS focused, because none are. Also, I'd recommend changing the button to a 'button' tag because it separates it in terms of tag name from the other input boxes.

Hope this helped, and let me know if you have any questions.

```js
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     for(var i = 1 ; i < inputs.length; i ++){
        inputs[i].onfocus = function(){
                this.setAttribute('class','focused');
        }
     }
  function run(){
   var inputBox = document.getElementsByClassName('focused')[0];
    if(inputBox){
      inputBox.value += "1";
      inputBox.setAttribute('class','blurred');
    }
  }
```

```html
  
 <input type=button name="btn1" value="1" OnClick="run()"id="button"><br     />
  <form name="calc">
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1">
  <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2">
  <input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt3">
  </form>
```